# Execute Javascriptcode in OnClick event of a Button

Tags: javascript, android, button, layout, webview

I have a webview and a Button (out of webview) in my layout.
I want to know if there is any way to execute javascript code when i click in the button (using its OnClick event for example)

EDIT:

I have this HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="PruebaAlert.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <!--Your content here-->

    </body>
</html>
```

I have my function JS in PruebaAlert.js

```
function myJSFunction(){
           alert('hello, i was hit by Android button');
```

}

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int pulsado = 0;

//Controla que estamos usando el layout web_view_not_visible
boolean web_view_not_visible = true;
TextView text;
Button button;

WebView myWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.web_view_not_visible);

    myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/StackOverflow.html");

    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


    if(true){
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);


        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("WebView Debug" , "Entre en onClick()");
                myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:myJSFunction()");
            }
        });

    }

}

}
```

I click on Button (it is on bottom of the layout) but alert don't show. If i open HTML in Chrome or Firefox it's work fine

What happen?

---

Thanks!

Comment: see html treated as a string in eclipse ..so convert html code in to string

Comment: i have that file in assets folder and i open it with WebView. It'is work fine so i don't understand why convert in to string :S

Comment: so now your code is fine...right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function myJSFunction(){
               alert('hello, i was hit by Android button');
            }
        </script>
        //OR
        <script type="text/javascript" src="yourJSFile.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <!--Your content here-->
    </body>
</html>
```

**yourJSFile.js**

```
function myJSFunction(){
    alert('hello, i was hit by Android button');
}
```

**onCreate**

```
myWebView.loadUrl("yourHtml.html");
```

Then just call javascript when button is clicked:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
   public void onClick(View v){
      myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:myJSFunction();");
   }
});
```

Comment: But where do i put my javascript file? i have a file (Hello.js) with only this line:  "alert("Hello") and i want this alert to show in webview. Thanks!

Comment: @user2203377: The js file should be present in the html that you are loading.

Comment: I have used your code but i don't show the alert. I put the code in my first post. Do you see any error? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I had to set WebChromeClient and it's work! So thanks very much!

Comment: This code works fine. but how to call javascript for selected text?

Answer (score 1):

You can call the javascript like this

```
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:test('arguments')");
```

As for your second question that you asked in your comment.

```
Where do i put my javascript file?
```

There are two ways webview can load a page one loading a html page from the application and second pointing to external site. In both the cases the JS should be placed where the HTML will look for it.